# Trying to understand membership type cluster-edge_betweeness (igraph) R language

Tags: r, igraph

I am trying to understand the return type of the membership function used in ceb<-cluster-edge_betweeness

Saying

```
ceb<-cluster-edge_betweeness(g)
data<-membership(ceb)
print data
 a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j  k  l  m  n  o  p  q  r  s  t 
 1  2  3  4  5  4  6  6  7  8  9 10 11  3  6 12  5  3 13  6
```

I want to able to say for node a which clusters are you a member of

```
print data[2]
```

gives

```
b
2
```

Saying

```
print data[[2]]
```

gives

```
[1] 2
```

I want to be able to write something that returns the value of  'b' part of strange data type.

```
class(data)
```

gives

```
membership

typeof(data)
```

gives

```
double

data[2:10]
```

gives

```
b c d e f g h i j 
2 3 4 5 4 6 6 7 8
```

what I was hoping to say was some code that said

vertex f is a member of cluster 4

The data[[6]]  will give me 4, how do I get access to the f part ?

`

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just discovered that its possible to say

```
data [['a']]
```

and the expected answer, so this data type is some type of array addressed by the node name.  I guess my questions needs to be how can I get a list of keys which such a construct